# How do I import the providedIn: root singleton service?

Tags: angular, singleton

Let's say this is my simple service:

```
 @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class UserpreferencesService {
      color: string = 'yellow';

      constructor() {
        console.log("UserpreferencesService instance created");
     }
    }
```

I have two components where I want to use the color field from the service. If I import in each component the service it won't act as singleton: I'll have a new instance every time I switch components. Here is the [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/github/serj99/angtest/tree/singleton).

If I don't import anything the service won't be recognized: "Cannot find name UserpreferencesService". This is how I use the service inside component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-compone',
  templateUrl: './compone.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./compone.component.css']
})
export class ComponeComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private UserPreferences: UserpreferencesService) {
    this.UserPreferences.color = 'green';
  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

The service is not part of any providers list. How can I solve this?

Comment: If you don't add the service to any `providers` list, it will be a singleton. You can then inject it in every component. I am not sure what you mean by `import` in your question.

Comment: You must have an `import` statement in order to use the service in the component. Importing does not create an instance of the service; it just allows to refer to the service code.

Comment: Tested this before too. Why do I get the service constructor message on every component change? This means there's a new instance of service every time I change components, no singleton.

Comment: If you can create a stackblitz reproducing the problem, it will be easier for us to help.

Comment: This should work fine. How do you ‘switch components’?

Comment: I've updated. @MikeOne There's a route for each component.

Comment: Sure - but when testing, are you actually using routerLinks clicks or are you refreshing the browser? Looking at your stackblitz - you have no way of navigating (you have no buttons or links). so the only way to get from one to two is type it in the address bar. That is a full refresh of your app. Bad test like this..

Comment: @MikeOne Yes, the problem resided here. I wasn't using routerLink.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be an import for the service in each component. 
My problem was that I was navigating from the address bar (this full refreshes the app). 
You have to use routerLink to have singleton service.